# SQL Server 2016 SSIS package fails with "Unexpected Termination"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016

I have an Integration Services project deployed to SQL Server 2016.
In this project I am extracting data from an old Oracle database using Oracle provider for OLEDB.
the extract package basically truncates a table in the destination (SQL Server 2016) database, and then uses a data flow task to extract a table of about 300,000 rows and about 80 columns (basically just creating a copy on the SQL Server).

when running the package using Visual studio we never ran into any problem. but when running the package from SSISDB, about half the times, the package fails with an "unexpected error". nothing appears in the SSIS log.

Looking into the events log finds the following error:

> Faulting application name: ISServerExec.exe, version: 13.0.4457.0, time stamp: 0x5a0384d1
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18666, time stamp: 0x58f32841
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00015608
>   Faulting process id: 0x37e8
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d36de21b43d295
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\ISServerExec.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 71f91df2-d9d5-11e7-80d7-005056a12e2d
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I have found notes of this problem in SQL Server 2012 with a hotfix by Microsoft, but none for SQL Server 2016.

Things I have tried:

1. update sql server 2016 to the latest version
2. change the sql server agent user to a local admin.
3. change the buffer size and rows
4. change the max concurrent executions from -1 to 1 *(I don't run more than 1 package at a time here)*

I also noticed that the failure sometimes happens after about 40 seconds (which is also the time it takes it to run successfully) and sometimes it lingers for about 8-10 minutes, even though the error is logged about 40 seconds from when it started.

Thanks for any help.

***Update***
I think it was a performance issue. when I reduced the number of rows loaded from 330K to 20K it worked 100% of the time.
So I Changed it to load incrementally (for a single package I didn't think it's a good idea to add RAM).

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you have any Execute Package Tasks in the offending package?

Comment: I'd be suspicious of the Oracle driver. Does the Oracle client match the database you are extracting from? In SSIS, which driver are you using? The  Microsoft one (which is just a wrapper) or the Oracle one?

Comment: No execute package task.
The Oracle driver is the Oracle one, not the Microsoft one.